# If ${n \choose 3} + {n+3-1 \choose 3} = (n)_3$, compute $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

If ${n \choose 3} + {n+3-1 \choose 3} = (n)_3$, compute $n$.

Just making sure I am on the right track...

Do I expand each piece out and solve algebraically?

Comment: what's $(n)_3$?

Comment: Yes, just expand everything, simplify, and solve the resulting quadratic.

Comment: @Alex: It’s the falling factorial $n(n-1)(n-2)$, also written $n^{\underline 3}$; the OP is using the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) for it.

Comment: Is there a certain way to expand ${n+3-1 \choose 3}$? Or does it expand like ${n \choose r}$

Answer (score 1):

This might be that weird notation introduced by Knuth. Anyhow, what could be useful here:
$$
\binom{n}{3} = \frac{(n+2)!}{(n-3)!3! (n+1)(n+2)}
$$
and subtract.

Comment: The notation has nothing to do with Knuth: Pochhammer died quite a few years before Knuth was born.

Comment: Knuth popularized it in 'Concrete Mathematics'

Comment: He did not: he popularized my preferred notation, $n^{\underline 3}$.

Comment: It's how I found out about it, and many other too. I'm sure CM has been read by way more people that Pochhammer's works. TBH I never came across it anywhere else. Perhaps I read the wrong papers :)

Comment: Several different notations are used, sometimes with conflicting meanings; if you read German, there’s a quick discussion of the notational confusion [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer-Symbol#Notation).