# Simplifying help: If ${n \choose 3} + {n+3-1 \choose 3} = (n)_3$, compute $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

If ${n \choose 3} + {n+3-1 \choose 3} = (n)_3$, compute $n$.

So far, I have:

$\frac{n!}{3! (n-3)!} + \frac{(n+2)!}{3! (n-1)!}$

Then I simplified to:

$\frac{1}{6} (n-2)(n-1)(n) + \frac{1}{6} (n)(n+1)(n+2)$

Is this correct, and if so, what is the next move? It needs to equal $(n)_3$.

Thanks!

Comment: what is $(n)_3$?

Comment: "n falling 3" = $(n)(n-1)(n-2)$

Comment: Note that ${n\choose 3}=\frac16(n)_3$, so you can simplify your expression to ${n+3-1\choose 3}=\frac56(n)_3$, and then factor $n$ out of this to leave yourself a quadratic.  OTOH, the appearance of '$n+3-1\choose 3$' leaves me suspecting that this question came out of a different one; what's the original problem?

Comment: You should probably refine your original question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163917/) looking for more details rather than asking another one with nearly identical title.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly ready.

Substitute $(n)_3 = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2)$, and you will see both sides are divisable by n. Thus, converting the result to a polinomial form, you will get an at most 2-grade equation, which will be soon very easy to solve.

$$\frac{1}{6}(n-2)(n-1)n + \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2) = n(n-1)(n-2)$$

Multiply with 6:

$$(n-2)(n-1)n + n(n+1)(n+2) = 6(n-2)(n-1)n$$

Minus $(n-2)(n-1)n$:

$$n(n+1)(n+2) = 5n(n-1)(n-2)$$

Divide both side with $n$:

$$(n+1)(n+2) = 5(n-1)(n-2)$$

$$n^2+3n+2 = 5(n^2-3n+2)$$

$$n^2+3n+2 = 5n^2-15n+10$$

$$4n^2-18n+8 = 0$$

$$2n^2-9n+4 = 0$$

$$n_{1,2}=\frac{9\pm \sqrt{81-4*2*4}}{4}=\frac{9\pm 7}{4} \in \{ \frac{1}{2}, 4\}$$

Only $\underline{\underline{4}}$ is integer, thus this is the only solution.